# How to export user profile QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, export

I want to export the user profile in QGIS to use it on another machine.

Comment: I think you can just copy and paste the one you want to replace the one you don't.  But you can always rename the one to be replaced prior to pasting to be sure, and if something goes wrong rename it back.  The profile folder is located here:  C:\Users\usernamehere\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3

Comment: when I pasted the user profile folder, I got a python error message from QGIS